# I get an error message with the status 404. When I want to send an attachment to a conversation using botbuilder for the ms-teams bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

My task is to transfer the file received from a third-party resource to the bot, and then to the user's chat without confirmation from the user, saving the file in the user's channel.
I am using bot builder 4 to create a bot for Teams. I need to send attachments to the user's chat. But when I try to do this, I get a 404 error in response.

the function I use

```
export async function getUploadedAttachment(turnContext) {
  const imageData = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../resources/image.png'));
  const connectorFactory = turnContext.turnState.get(turnContext.adapter.ConnectorFactoryKey);
  const connector = await connectorFactory.create(turnContext.activity.serviceUrl);
  const conversationId = turnContext.activity.conversation.id;
  const responce = connector.conversations.uploadAttachment(conversationId, {
    name: 'image.png',
    originalBase64: imageData,
    type: 'image/png'
  });

  // Retrieve baseUri from ConnectorClient for... something.
  const baseUri = connector.baseUri;
  const attachmentUri = baseUri + (baseUri.endsWith('/') ? '' : '/') + `v3/attachments/${encodeURI(response.id)}/views/original`;
  return {
    name: 'image.png',
    contentType: 'image/png',
    contentUrl: attachmentUri
  };
}
```

What do I get in response

```
code: undefined,
  statusCode: 404,
  request: WebResource {
    streamResponseBody: false,
    url: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/a%3A1dTMkfArgCiw6Rul0Ufyk1W4zUWY1l5VpU3wylTjckFCv03ywIqsN1pzD--fDRWupM92sb5rN6x0tl8U_gF6Z4ZwWC8n0KbcEWM5pd9GEKL7JogAp0IWnjzKWQRbxxaAQ/attachments',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
    body: '{}',
    query: undefined,
    formData: undefined,
    withCredentials: false,
    abortSignal: undefined,
    timeout: 0,
    onUploadProgress: undefined,
    onDownloadProgress: undefined,
    proxySettings: undefined,
    keepAlive: undefined,
    agentSettings: undefined,
    operationSpec: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      path: 'v3/conversations/{conversationId}/attachments',
      urlParameters: [Array],
      requestBody: [Object],
      responses: [Object],
      serializer: [Serializer]
    }
  },
  response: {
    body: '',
    headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
    status: 404
  },
  body: undefined
}
```

I also used an example from https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/15.handling-attachments

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teams uses different mechanisms for interacting with bot framework bots in many cases. Sample 15 is for other channels. In the samples repo, if you scroll down to 50 or so you will find Teams-specific samples. [Sample 56](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/56.teams-file-upload) concerns file uploads in Teams, and you should start from there instead.

Comment: As per stackoverflow rule: do not post link as answers as it might be removed.  The sample you linked to has been removed.